# Notification / Task Bar

Tags: android, notifications

Trying to add a second line to this so it shows the Name of my app and some additional info tried just duplicating the CharSequence but that wasn't it... thanks in advance

```
private void showNotification() {
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.title_bar);
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.title_bar2);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_notification, null,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Karan's request, please also do your best to ensure posted code examples compile successfully, unless of course you're stuck at a compiler error.

The code you posted wouldn't compile, even if it were more complete.  You cannot declare two identifiers in the same scope with the same name.

Comment: I understand that I must show code that is correct but that is why I ask questions on here because I don't know how to write it correctly ...I did find the answer though  Thank you for your help